# Как активировать EditText

Tags: java, android, android-dialog

У меня есть `EditText`  который при создании активити скрытый `editText.setVisibility(View.GONE)` , после чего при выполнении некого условия это текстовое поле должно появиться и что бы курсор в нем уже мигал , вместе с этим -  должна появится и  клавиатура. Я пробовал делать так, поле появляется,  но курсор в нем и клавиатура  - нет.  Что я не так делаю?

```
@Override
public void onQuestionDialogItemClick(int which) {
    messageCompose.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    etInputMsg.setEnabled(true);
    etInputMsg.setSelected(true);
}
```

Comment: методы `setEnabled()` и `setSelecteted()` не передают фокус на виджет. Первый управляет его активностью (доступен для взаимодействия с пользователем или нет), второй активирует выделение на виджете

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это покажет клавиатуру

```
InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager)context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
inputManager.showSoftInput(view, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
((InputMethodManager)context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).showSoftInput(view, 0);
```

Это даст фокус твоему EditText

```
etInputMsg.requestFocus();
```

Comment: где view == etInputMsg

Answer (score 1):

Возможно как-то так

```
@Override
public void onQuestionDialogItemClick(int which) {
    messageCompose.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    etInputMsg.setSelected(true);
    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager =(InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInputFromWindow(linearLayout.getApplicationWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0)
}
```

Comment: Клавиатура закрывается но курсор в начало строки не ставится почему то, попробовал добавить                 etInputMsg.setEnabled(true);